# Twitter Integration using OAuth in PHP

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am writing a website that interfaces with twitter (not just to pull data, but to publish an update when a new news item is added). Does anyone know any good php libraries that login to twitter (using oauth), can pull tweets, and post tweets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth lib is an old one but still maintained and fully support OAuth.

Comment: nice, just downloading it now. Is that just for authentication, or getting a script to download and upload stuff to twitter (mostly so the grabs aren't based on IP, but on your account.